# Exception with CreateKey of PublicKeyFactory of BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp

I'm trying to create an AsymmetricKeyParameter public key obj from an xml string like this:

```
public static AsymmetricKeyParameter xmlStringToPubKey(string xmlStr)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlStr))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
        return PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(Streamify(xdoc.Descendants("Modulus").First().Value));
    }
}
```

I get the following stack trace:

> at Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DefiniteLengthInputStream.ToArray()    at
>   Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Asn1InputStream.BuildObject(Int32 tag, Int32
>   tagNo, Int32 length)    at
>   Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Asn1InputStream.ReadObject()    at
>   Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Asn1Object.FromByteArray(Byte[] data)    at
>   Org.BouncyCastle.Security.PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(Byte[]
>   keyInfoData)    at TestConsole.PGP.xmlStringToPubKey(String xmlString)
>   in PGP.cs:line 141    at TestConsole.Test.Main(String[] args) in
>   Test.cs:line 22    at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

While there's very little to no documentation for c#, the method (CreateKey) description accepts a byte array or a Stream as parameters. I've tried numerous ways to convert the string into a byte, but still couldn't get it work. 
Any hints/help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey` method is expecting a stream containing an ASN.1 encoded [SubjectPublicKeyInfo](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.7) structure. The error you get indicates that the stream does not deliver a correctly encoded ASN.1 object.

If you know the type of key you want to create you can directly create the `AsymmetricKeyParameter` subtype instance from the key parameters.

For example for a RSA key:

```
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(xdoc.Descendants("Modulus").First().Value);
BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(xdoc.Descendants("Exponenet").First().Value);
AsymmetricKeyParameter param = new RsaKeyParameters(false, modulus, exponent);
```

Comment: Thanks. A follow-up: how would I create another AsymmetricKeyParameter of the private key considering the fact that I have direct access to D (private key) or to P or Q?

Comment: Creating a private key is almost straightforward: (in pseudo-code) AsymmetricKeyParameter param = new RsaKeyParameters(true, p*q, d); You need to have access to the private exponent "d" and the modulus m = p*q